# JointJS: Embed Pais e Filhos

Tags: javascript, mysql, json

Boas,

Eu estou a trabalhar com JointJS mas de uma maneira dinâmica.

Neste momento estou a tentar fazer o embed dos elementos 'parent' e 'child'.

Depois de fazer o select com a info dos child e parent, faço um get para ir buscar essa informação:
QUERY

```
<?php public function getElemLinks($param)
{
    $this->cleanErrors();
    $this->sql->cleanErrors();

    $query="SELECT
                linkEl.ID,
                linkEl.id_arquitectura,
                linkEl.nome_link,
                linkEl.source_box,
                linkEl.target_box,
                linkEl.link_texto,
                linkEl.link_textPos,
                linkEl.link_strokeCor,
                linkEl.link_strokeWidth,
                linkEl.link_router
            FROM
                arquitecturas_link_elementos as linkEl          
            WHERE
                linkEl.id_arquitectura = '".$param['arquitectura']."'
            ";

    $this->sql->query($query);

    //echo $query;

    if($this->sql->hasErrors()){
        $this->errors = $this->errors + $this->sql->errors;
        return false;
    }

    while($row = $this->sql->fetchRow())
    {
        $res[] = $row;
    }

    if($this->sql->hasErrors()){
        $this->errors = $this->errors + $this->sql->errors;
        return false;
    }

    return $res;
} ?>
```

GET - JSON

```
$.getJSON( "controller/diagramas.php", {
    arquitectura: servicoUtilizado,
}, function(infoElementos){ 
    $.each(infoElementos["parents"], function(prindex, objp){
        //Embed boxes 'filhos' nas áreas 'pai'
        console.log(object.caixas[objp.parentNome].embed(object.caixas[objp.nome_caixa]));
    });


});
```

O que acontece é que, quando ao implementar este código, os elementos child ficam presos e não dão para fazer drag e assim que movo o elemento parent os elementos child não o acompanham, como suposto.

Comment: Resolveu seu problema?

Comment: Ainda não. Já experimentei várias opções mas não resolvia o que queria

Comment: Consegue dar um print no erro?